# Excluding variations of word based on negated preceding term

Tags: python, nlp, data-mining

I am looking at data mining records for rabies, currently a simplified version of my regex is as follows:

```
(?<!not seen)(?<!not found)(?<!not observed)\srabies
```

Is there a way of having "not" "**(something)**" "rabies" where the blank is representative of any subsequent negative comment, therefore I do not need to have huge list of possible combinations to say "not seen rabies"?

Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems like a natural language processing task, not a regex task. Regex doesn't have any concept of the meaning of language. I recommend looking into [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, really appreciate it. I'll look into it :)

Comment: Or are you just looking for a regex `not <any word> rabies`? That can be done with regex like `/not +\w+ +rabies/`.

Comment: Certainly the more simpler approach the nltk stuff looks really interesting but might be beyond the scopes of me. Anyways, thanks again 